# Javascript errors from Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, adsense

On several of my adsense running sites, I have been getting the following errors:

> **Unable to post message to [http://]googleads.g.doubleclick.net.
>   Recipient has origin
>   http://www.anekdotz.com.**
>
> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access
>   frame with URL
>   [http://]www.anekdotz.com/ from frame
>   with URL
>   [http://]googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-9099580055602120&output=html&h=250&slotname=9210181593&w=300&flash=10.0.42&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anekdotz.com%2F&dt=1269901036429&correlator=1269901036438&frm=0&ga_vid=711000587.1269901037&ga_sid=1269901037&ga_hid=654061172&ga_fc=0&u_tz=-240&u_his=2&u_java=1&u_h=900&u_w=1440&u_ah=878&u_aw=1436&u_cd=24&u_nplug=10&u_nmime=101&biw=1365&bih=806&eid=44901212&fu=0&ifi=1&dtd=153&xpc=Xkfk1oufPQ&p=http%3A//www.anekdotz.com.
>   **Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

(from the Chrome javascript console)

The ads seem to show properly and it doesn't affect my native javascript code.  However sometimes these errors seem to slow down page loading.  How can I fix this problem?

(I modified the URLs to let me post this as I'm a new user)

Comment: Is anekdotz.com your web site?

Comment: Same problem here.  This post is from almost a year ago!  If its a google problem, how is it that it's not fixed!? It's also killing other js on the site.  According to this it seems to be related to leaderboard ads only.. http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=4045dd1fdae7ff47&hl=en

Comment: Submit the issue to google adsense....

Comment: @user257493 - there are many examples of people with the same problem on the adsense groups/support pages, and I haven't seen anyone with a fix.  Will submit the issue in the end, but I know it takes an age.

Comment: same with google maps iframes, yeah google can break rules. hope it doesnt ruin the seo ranking ;-)

Comment: Has this been solved? I get the same error `Unable to post message to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net. Recipient has origin http://www.mydomain....` and I can't fix it!

I tested with the latest Chrome, FF 7, IE8 and 9, as well as the latest Safari.

Comment: Is there any solution to this? The marked answer does not seem to be a solution for me...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Google have messed up their script. There's not much you can do about it.

For some reason `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.net/pagead/expansion_embed.js`, included in the parent page by the AdSense scripts, is trying to send information about the advert into a newly-written `<iframe>` created to hold the advert, using the new HTML5 [postMessage](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/comms.html#dom-window-postmessage-2) facility:

```
            ha(this, function (f, e) {
                d[Pa](this.a[A]+"|"+f+":"+e, this.la)
            });
```

Yeah. Some nice minified/obfuscated code there. Trust me, `Pa` is `'postMessage'`!

The `targetOrigin` argument in this call, `this.la` is set to `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net`. However, the new iframe was written with its `src` set to `about:blank`. This doesn't match the target origin, so the browser must refuse to send the message. Only Chrome seems to be dropping an actual whinge to the console log about it though.

No idea why it's doing this at all, never mind why it's not just using `'*'` as a target origin... I'm not really feeling like wading into the obfuscated script to find out. However, this error should not cause page loading to slow down. If you're seeing pauses it's usually resolving and fetching other external scripts.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the heads up.  Yeah I'm not sure whether it's actually slowing the page down, but it brings up the browsers "loading page" notification at the bottom while the page appears loaded.  This is annoying and might also bother some users who think they should wait until their browser shuts up.

I hope they do something about this soon.

Comment: I am also having this error, not particularly any slowness but I am realizing that it's making other JS to stop working, like fb social apps integration. I wonder how is it that this hasn't been fixed already.

Comment: May I add: this only happens to me on a specific Chrome session where I have an ad blocker installed. I disabled the plugin for particular URLs, still the origin error message is triggered. If open the same site in incognito window, the problem disapears.

Comment: Is this answer still valid in 2018?

Answer (score 15):

Google's trying to exploit a browser quirk whereby some browsers ignore the same-origin policy for windows with about:blank as the URL, allowing that window to submit XMLHttpRequest or, in this case, postMessage requests to any site.

As far as I know, browsers have recently been disabling this behaviour. You must have one such patched browser.

Hopefully, this broken functionality doesn't affect your ability to earn money from the ads.

It's annoying for your site to generate Javascript errors through no fault of your own, but it is a possibility you must accept when you run someone else's Javascript on your page.

Comment: "allowing that window to submit ... postMessage requests to any site" How is that an exploit? `postMessage` may be called on any view without having to account for same origin restrictions.

Comment: It may be *called* that way, sure.  But whether the message itself is sent depends on whether the target window, at the time the message is received, has the origin described by the second argument to `postMessage`.  It seems that's not the case here.  (As for why it could be an exploit, quoting from MDC: "If postMessage were used to transmit a password, it would be absolutely critical that this argument be a URI whose origin is the same as the intended receiver of the message containing the password, to prevent interception of the password by a malicious third party.")

Answer (score 8):

It's normal because your browser prevents CSRF attacks from other websites.

To allow `googleads...` to access your website and solve this problem, create a file named `crossdomain.xml` in your webroot and fill it with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy 
  SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="googleads.g.doubleclick.net" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

To test it, go to your domain http://your-domain.com/crossdomain.xml and make sure there are no errors for that page. You also allowed to use wildcards, etc (look at reference). When you're done, refresh your page.
Hope that helps.

Live example:
http://www.blanjamudah.com/crossdomain.xml

Reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery
http://curtismorley.com/2007/09/01/flash-flex-tutorial-how-to-create-a-crossdomainxml-file/

Comment: This didn't work for me, it might be relevant for Flash Player.

Answer (score 4):

A crossdomain.xml file in the site root allowing access to googleads.g.doubleclick.net should fix it.

See this page, http://www.warriorforum.com/adsense-ppc-seo-discussion-forum/458906-adsense-blank-space-problem.html

Answer (score 4):

For those who land on this page after searching for the domain and protocol error code:

AdSense has released a new [async version](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en) of their javascript that addressed the cross-domain errors being generated when we used their older embed code. When we used their standard embed code on our AJAX-heavy site, we got the cross-domain error. When we implemented their async code, and [in combination with a properly defined crossdomain.xml](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/156396?hl=en) the cross-domain error went away.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case of the error message masking the real cause. The real cause is probably some kind of Adsense misconfiguration; unfortunately Adsense doesn't seem to do sufficient checks to give a more relevant error message.

I had this error myself and came to this conclusion after researching the forums, where some people reported it was fixed after verifying their bank account or whatever. In my case, my server-side environment was messing with the google_ad_client parameter, so the real problem was that parameter being null. Once I fixed that, ads were showing and no more error message.

So in practice, it's really nothing to do with same-origin policy. Now that the adsense code is correct, I'm even now able to show ads when running on localhost, as well as on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just got a similar problem. Not sure if it's related, but I'll explain anyway.

I had two ads showing on my page and wanted to "refactor" the code by only calling this script once at the end of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

My ads broke and I figured out that this script tag has to be placed just after each ads var script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-872346872364872364";
google_ad_slot = "719238712983";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
```

But when I had reverted my changes the first script tag was still also placed at the bottom of my page and thusly trying to load another one of my script-tags as an ad. This failed and I got this error you saw.

So check that you keep the two ads script tags after eachother and no place else, ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-872346872364872364";
google_ad_slot = "719238712983";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply moving `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>` to the top of the page above the ads, instead of below, fixed this for me

Comment: Strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

In the Sites tab in your Google Adsense dashboard (web or app version). Make sure your site is setup with **your-domain.com** (or whichever tld) as the domain and **www.your-domain.com** as a subdomain.