# Google Adsense breaking JavaScript on page: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: javascript, adsense

My homepage loads fine, the slider and the adsense: http://www.thiswebguy.com/

Now if you take a look on a category page, and open the console, it looks like Adsense is causing me problems? http://www.thiswebguy.com/category/seo/onpage-seo/

The exact error I am receiving is:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL  http://www.thiswebguy.com/category/seo/on-page-seo-seo/ from frame with URL  http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/html/r20130311/r20130206/zrt_lookup.html.  Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Even if you look in the console log on the homepage - there are so many JavaScript errors all caused by Google apparently!

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript errors from Google Adsense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541797/javascript-errors-from-google-adsense)

Comment: nothing you can do about it I'm afraid

Comment: The link gives a 404.

Comment: Sorry - http://www.thiswebguy.com/category/seo/onpage-seo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled JavaScript and loaded the home page using Chrome, `Version 27.0.1444.3 dev-m`.

When hovering over the thumbnail section of the slider, the thumbnails are displayed.

After loading the "On Page SEO" page (again, with JavaScript disabled), the first three thumbnails appear to be missing.

It looks like there may be an problem with the page pre-JavaScript/slider initialization that's causing the issue.