# Adsense error: "Blocked a frame with origin.."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, adsense

The full error is:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://deltavmap.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Where deltavmap is my site. I've found related questions to this kind of error but none that have given me a solution. The error doesn't seem to appear in anyother browser excpet for Chrome but no ads display regardless. Any ideas? Cheers

Edit: Ads started loading, but the error remains (in fact is prints out every couple of seconds)

Comment: I have the same error. Maybe the Ads did not load because you may have started a new AdSense ad and it won't load until the spiders have crawled the site. However I'm not sure what is causing the error but as long as the ads are loading that is all I care about.

Comment: Read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541797/javascript-errors-from-google-adsense

Answer (score 1):

For me the errors vanished on their own. One day when I checked the browser console they were gone. This has happened to me more than once.

It could have had something to do with the fact that my DNS settings had changed. I think I changed the IP address the domain pointed to shortly before.