# issues with iFrame in iOS app?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, mobile, cross-platform

We are developing a cross platform app and facing issues at the uses of `iFrame` only.
Page in iFrame is not loading properly and having issues while scrolling, after some time app is crashing.
But app is working fine on android.

Is there any issues related to or specific to the uses of `iFrame` on iOS?

Code we are using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>       
    <title></title>   
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 , minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">  
</head>
<body>
    Test Page
    <iframe src="http://www.devicepixelratio.com/" style="height: 400px;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Getting error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x18474b30 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=requested_URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=requested_URL}
```

Comment: load this way <div id="content" style="height: auto; width: auto; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">
        <iframe height="100%" scrolling="no" width="100% "> iframe content here </iframe>
</div>

Comment: @Agent: this change sort outs the scrolling issue but the app still scrashes

Answer (score 0):

When I open the website [www.devicepixelratio.com](http://www.devicepixelratio.com/) in Safari on my Mac and I got the following error message in the debug console:

`Blocked a frame with origin "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.devicepixelratio.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

This error occurs 9 times every time I load the page. It appears to be an issue with cross domain scripting, which is most likely throwing an error in the UIWebView and causing the crash. I'm not sure what server type you're using, so I won't attempt to help you with the CORS setup, but here's a link to another Stack Overflow question with many answers that may help:

[Javascript errors from Google Adsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541797/javascript-errors-from-google-adsense)