# Adsense protocol mismatch

Tags: adsense

I keep getting this error about a protocol mismatch of https vs http with my Adsense ads and don't understand how to fix this.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net" from 
accessing a frame with origin "http://example.com".  The frame requesting 
access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol
of "http". Protocols must match.
```

I could not found any solution to this,why no one is facing this issue ??

Comment: When including adsense code (javascript) in your html page be sure its an http link and not an https link

Comment: yes it is  http link  <script async src="http//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

Comment: hum its `http//` and it should be `http://`

Comment: sorry typing mistake take it //pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js which also means http://

Comment: try to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ` on your php or you can add it on your htaccess `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541797/javascript-errors-from-google-adsense

Comment: I already have that in my server( and  this issue clearly says about http vs https...  ( by the way, thanks a lot for your interst in this issue)