# Rails Google Adsense Cross Domain Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cross-domain, adsense

I'm implementing Google Adsense in a rails application and I'm getting errors in my browser.

> [Error] Blocked a frame with origin  "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net"
>       from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

The error is present on the production server as well as localhost, so ignore that detail.

My understanding of what's going on here is Google's Adsense script expects a secure connection, therefore it barks at the protocol mismatch.  Ads are still displaying, but I have no idea if Adsense is functioning correctly on all fronts.

Is there a workaround for this programatically? There has to be a way to get this working given all the regular http pages with Adsense ads.  What am I missing?

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541797/javascript-errors-from-google-adsense